# Why can't jQuery parents() find my element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

I just cannot get this (pretty simple) function to work correctly, parents() doesn't seem to find the div I want and fade it out :(

```
$('.deleteButton').click( function() {

    var img = $(this).attr('href');
    img = "../"+img;

    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? (This cannot be undone!)');
    if (answer) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/deletePhoto.php',
            data: 'img='+img,
            type: 'POST',
            mode: 'abort',
            success: function(){
                $(this).parents("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="photo">
    <img alt="" src="../static/images/photos/tmp/1.jpg">
    <div class="overlay" style="opacity: 0;">
        <p class="process success message">
            <a href="process_photo.php?img=../static/images/photos/tmp/1.jpg">Process this photo</a>
        </p>
        <p class="delete error message">
            <a href="../static/images/photos/tmp/1.jpg" class="deleteButton">Delete image</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `$(this).parents(".photo").fadeOut('fast');` and `$(this).cloest("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');` but nothing is connecting :(

Comment: $(this) will be for ajax function. not the click handler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. Inside the `success` callback from ajax, `this` does not refer to what you think it does - it refers literally to the function itself.

You should cache a copy of `$(this)` outside the ajax call, and use that:

```
$('.deleteButton').click( function() {
   var $img = $(this);

   //....//

   $.ajax({
        url: 'scripts/deletePhoto.php',
        data: 'img='+img,
        type: 'POST',
        mode: 'abort',
        success: function(){
            $img.parents("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });

   // ... //
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you meant to put the $ in front of the variables? Wouldn't that mess with jQuery?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - no it was entirely intentional. It is a convention among many jQuery devs to prefix the variable name with `$` when it refers to a jQuery object. This stops you double wrapping a variable and no, it does not interfere with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't find your object is because `$(this)` does not point to the object you think it points to.
You're using it inside the callback function of an Ajax call, whose context is different than the click event handler.

Stick it in a variable before you do the Ajax call, then you'll be fine:

```
$('.deleteButton').click( function() {

    var img = $(this).attr('href');
    img = "../"+img;

    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? (This cannot be     undone!)');
    if (answer) {

        var my_item = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/deletePhoto.php',
            data: 'img='+img,
            type: 'POST',
            mode: 'abort',
            success: function(){
                my_item .parents("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the click handler you have to keep a reference to the pressed button, because otherwise `this` will be "overwritten" inside the AJAX success handler:

```
$('.deleteButton').click( function() {
    var img = $(this).attr('href'),
    $self = $(this);

    img = "../"+img;
```

Then, inside the success handler:

```
$self.parents("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');
```

Btw, I would suggest making this change inside the `$.ajax` call:

```
data: 'img=' + encodeURIComponent(img),
```

This avoids potentially sending a malformed query string to your server side script.

Answer (score 1):

you need cache the current event and use those variable. It's a scoping issue.

```
var currObj=$(this); cache the current event and use those variable. 

$('.deleteButton').click( function() {
var $currObj=$(this); // cache the current event. 
    var img = currObj.attr('href');
    img = "../"+img;

    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? (This cannot be undone!)');
    if (answer) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/deletePhoto.php',
            data: 'img='+img,
            type: 'POST',
            mode: 'abort',
            success: function(){
                $currObj.parents("div.photo").fadeOut('fast');
            }
        });
    }
return false;
});
```

Comment: in your example, `currObj` is already a jQuery object - so no need to wrap it in `$()` again!

Comment: A good convention is to use $ for jQuery objects:  var $currObj=$(this);